# Variable in WildFly: Cannot resolve expression on Linux

Tags: linux, wildfly

My setting

**standalone.conf.bat**

```
set "DBO_PATH_CONFIG=D:/test"
set "MOBILE_KEYSTORE=jboss.mobile.keystore"
```

**standalone.conf**

```
set "DBO_PATH_CONFIG=/opt/!!!"
set "MOBILE_KEYSTORE=jboss.mobile.keystore"
```

**standalone.xml**

```
    <security-realm name="SslRealm">
        <server-identities>
            <ssl>
                <keystore path="${env.DBO_PATH_CONFIG}/${env.MOBILE_KEYSTORE}" keystore-password="rmi+ssl"/>
            </ssl>
        </server-identities>
    </security-realm>
```

**Properties**

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
 <bindings>
  <simple name="java:/propertiesFileName" value="NONE" /> 
  <simple name="java:/propertiesFileNameV1" value="${env.DBO_PATH_CONFIG}/V1.properties" /> 
  <simple name="java:/propertiesFileNameV2" value="${env.DBO_PATH_CONFIG}/V2.properties" /> 
  </bindings>
  <remote-naming /> 
  </subsystem>
```

---

On Windows all works fine but on Linux I have this error:

```
10:57:34,512 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "SslRealm")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${env.DBO_PATH_CONFIG}/${env.MOBILE_KEYSTORE}'"
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux it's `export` not `set`. I also don't think you can have a directory called `!!!`. `!` has a special meaning in bash.

Comment: Most file systems allow any characters (bytes), except the directory separator (`/`) and the null character. Syntax of the current shell (bash etc.) is an other question (single quotes help).